# Remote hosts password file PhpStorm linux

Tags: phpstorm

Was using PhpStorm 2017 version then the macbook died.

I never did a backup or exported any password.

I'm on a new machine and want to import the existing remote host passwords

I read some answers like

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207074025-webServers-xml-format#5275025

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170108

They talk about using **keepass** or **keychain**, but it's too generic, what are the exact steps? And is there a way to use them at all if the original computer is dead and I only have access to the HD? How do I use them to "move" passwords to the new machine? OS is Mojave

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following worked

- On the dead computer take copy the file login.keychain in ~/Library/Keychains folder (it may be a hidden folder)
- ⁩On the new computer open utilities > Keychain access
- File > Add keychain
- Select the file you copied (recommended you rename first to avoid confusion)

If you're missing the hostnames in phpstorm they're stored in

~/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2018.2/options/webServers.xml